# Laravel application starting problem, from xampp server

Tags: laravel, mariadb, xampp

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

I have encountered this problem a lot, I try to delete xampp, when I reinstall it it works fine for about 2 3 months and after 2 3 months I face this problem again....

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, see: https://tableplus.com/blog/2019/08/host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server.html

The solution:

> 1. Access to the MySQL configuration file and add the --skip-grant-tables option.

> 2. Restart the server

> 3. Then repair the user table:

```
CHECK TABLE user;
REPAIR TABLE user;
```

> 4. Remove --skip-grant-tables and restart the mysql server.